# ACF plugin categories bug in WordPress 3.9

Tags: categories, custom-field, advanced-custom-fields

i recently started using ACF plugin, i noticed that variables for custom fields i created and use in categories are saved in ‘wp_options’ tables, and although i am doing everything right they do not appear in the front-end i get a bool(false) for the field, i do not know if this has something to do with the WordPress update and the way it handles categories but i noticed that category metadata are stored in wp_postmeta table. So now i can not get the data to show on front-end everything works great in back-end.

The interesting part is if i add the field in the first post of this category (maybe i should mention this is a custom section not the default category-post one that i use as a portfolio) the call on the category will start getting data, the ones that i specify on the post.

Could anyone please help me or suggest anything else that i need to check, i am using WordPress 3.9 and ACF 4.3.6. This might even be a template related bug, but since i am not that familiar with WordPress architecture and i have yet to receive any answer from plugin developers i thought of asking here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after some time time and the support of the guys in ACF i got through this. My template was accessing category data only by reference, a variable was created that referenced to the category id, and by that variable the category name and other data were called.

Thankfully the guys at ACF have thought through that and the only thing i had to add was the variable in the classic function the_field(‘field_name’,$variable) and everything worked great.